# Running MNIST Dataset Jupyter python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Help! I'm new to this IM trying to run a project but don't understand what to do on the part 4...any helpers? I'm not sure exactly what its asking or what to do.

MNIST Dataset Notebook

Overview
Script in this notebook is gives a demo on how tho parse the mnist dataset to csv/python memory, So that it can utilized for analysis. The below function converts the unzipped data obtained from http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ to csv format and stores in the local disk.

Instruction to run this script:

1. Download the datasets (total of 4 datasets) from: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
2. Unzipp the files and copy to the new folder called "mnist_data"
3. This newly created folder should be placed inside the folder where script is located.
4. **Create an instance of the class "DataConverterToCsv" with "[folder_name/]" as parameter**
5. Run the main function of the instance "DataConverterToCsv".

Comment: hmm..Homework??

Comment: no just a project I done a while back and I had someone help me run it before, but I cant exactly remember what they done on the bold part. Up until then im good...